# SSRS no data label for 100% chart

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, reporting-services-2016

I have created a SSRS 2017 report with a pie chart. The dataset returns the number of 3 different values/sections (total "green", total "yellow", total "red").

Now I want to show the data labels (-> pictures). I switched to line-chart, added the formula e.g.

`= IIf(Fields!red.Value=0, "", "#PERCENT"+ chr(10)+ "(#VALY)")`

to each line/section.

It works fine (-> picture 1) but e.g. for the case when I have 2 zero sections and only 1 section with 100%, the data labels are not shown. For each value > 0 < 100 the data labels are visible.

I also tried it without the formula/default values but the problem also occurs.

Does anyone know the issue?

Thx in advance for your replies!!

**Pie chart with different values**

[image: pie chart with different values]

**100 percent pie chart**

[image: 100 percent pie chart]

Comment: Can you post an example of the data?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need to do is update the expression. It would also depend on how you have the series label data setup.

`= "#PERCENT"+ chr(10)+ "(#VALY)"`

Comment: I think this will not do it.. I want to eliminate the 0 values. But I tried the formula without the IF statement and it also does not show the 100% values.

Answer (score 0):

[Query for data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFiS7.png)

I use this simple Query as data set.
So aggregations are done via SQL Query, not by SSRS.

All I want is that the 96 green data/100% are visible as label on the diagram, but it doesn't work...

The problem also occurs for line diagram, so it has nothing to do with the pie chart..